# docker port publish (remapping) doesn't work for http port

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, linux-containers

I created an asp.net service, exposing a webservice at 3188. It uses Kestrel server.

I published this via Linux container on local machine, with port mapping as `5188:3188`.
I cannot access this, `http://localhost:5188/diagnostics`.

If I publish on local machine, with port mapping as `3188:3188`, it works, and url `http://localhost:3188/diagnostics` yields a response.

How do I fix this issue, and publish specifically on port 5188, so, I can have similar services on different ports.

Comment: Might you have the mapping backwards? The first port is the one inside the container, so I think you would want `3188:5188`.

Comment: @AlexWatt The first port is the host port and the second port is the container port.